# Cadastrar array de forms no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tenho um formulário que é dinâmico, o usuário escolhe quantos input irá aparecer.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php $g = $_GET['id']; ?>
    <form method="post" action="upload.php?id=<?php echo $g ?>">
        <?php $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $qtd = $_GET['qtd'];

            $_SESSION['qtd'] = $qtd;

            $a = 0;
            while($a != $qtd){
                $a++;
            echo '
                <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" name="pergunta[]" placeholder="Pergunta n° '.$a.'">
              </div>     
              </div>
            ';}?>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
</form>
```

os names são passados todos em array, como posso estar cadastrando esses forms no banco de dados?
tentei com o seguinte código php e não consegui.

php

```
session_start();
require_once '../../../db/connect.php';

$id = $_get['id'];

foreach($_POST["pergunta"] as $pergunta) {
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO questao (questao,quiz_id) VALUES (".$pergunta.")") or die("Erro  query.<br>Mensagem do servidor: ".mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: Você colocou a tag <form> e o action da mesma? Se possível, coloque-a.

Comment: Coloquei sim. Aliás o action está indo normalmente. Mas não tá dando insert no banco de dados

Comment: coloque todo o código do seu form por favor

Comment: editei o código.

Comment: tente alterar os seu $_POST e $_GET para $_REQUEST

Comment: de todo código?